# ItemsControl - Custom ItemContainer

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I want to create a custom "Wizard"-Control.

So I derived a "Wizard" from Selector and created a "WizardPage" derived from HeaderedContentControl. Everything works fine, when I add the "WizardPages" directly to the "Wizard"'s Content itself.

In Code: This works

```
<ctrl:Wizard>
    <ctrl:WizardPage Header="Page 1" Content="Some Stuff" />
</ctrl:Wizard>
```

Then I thought: Hey, it would be great if you can put random stuff in the Wizard's Content and if needed he creates a wrapper around it, just like the ListBox with the ListBoxItems (I definately need a wrapper, because the WizardPage needs the properties "CanLeavePage" and "AlreadyVisited").

In Code: I want that this works (Groups is a list of whatever, which I can template somewhere to WizardPage)

```
<ctrl:Wizard ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" />
```

So I tried:

```
protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return item is WizardPage;
}

protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new WizardPage();
}
```

When I set breakpoints on those two methods I can see that IsItemItsOwnContainer gets called, but GetContainerForItemOverride never gets called.

What am I missing here?

The concept looks like this:

[image: SetupWizard]

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me and i don't see a problem. So what is the actual problem? Is the picture not what you want? How does your WizardPage look like? In code and in xaml. Does it have any content? Have you overriden the default style on both your items control and your container? Using [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) is a great help in finding bugs with view elements in wpf.

Comment: WizardPage is just a HeaderedContentControl with some extra Properties.

Comment: My problem is that the ItemsContainerGenerator doesn't generate items.

Comment: Ok you don't get items generated. Whats the "Groups" property? Whats in there? How does your view model look like. You need to provide more information to better help you. Is the Groups Property a collection? Is it an ObservableList? Because it needs to notify the view that something was added. We need more code, perfect is a small compilable example of what exactly is not working.

Comment: I created a VS2012 test project. My problem is not that the left list is not displayed but that the ICG is not generating items: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7344405/SetupTest.zip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after checking your code its clear why it doesn't work. Your Wizard class is a Selector so its an ItemsControl, but in your wizard control template you don't use any of ItemsControl stuff, inside the Template you use a ListBox, which is an ItemsControl itself, and there you bind The Wizards ItemsSource to the ItemsSource of the listbox. So in the ListBox is now the ItemContainerGenerator called to generate ListBoxItems, because effectively the list box is doing all the work, while the wizard does nothing except rerouting the ItemsSource property.

You need to greatly modify your Wizard Template to make it work. Btw. you can easily derive the Wizard class from the ListBox.

Comment: Exactly. I tried a "ItemsPresenter" instead of the listBox, but it didn't work. What do you mean by "greatly modify"?

Comment: Well don't place a ListBox inside your ItemsControl. Do you want your ItemsControl to be an actual ItemsControl or do you want it to host another ItemsControl? You need an ItemsPresenter and if you use the ItemsPresenter you need to supply an ItemsPanel, so your ItemsControl knows how to layout the individual Items. You can also use a Panel directly in your ControlTemplate and set the [IsItemsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.isitemshost.aspx) property

Comment: Btw. Have you considered overriding the TabControl for your purpose? In WPF i follow a general guideline on how to create new controls. If you need to achieve something try these in this order: Change Properties or style <> Use attached behaviors <> New ControlTemplate <> UserControl <> Subclass closest control (Listbox, TextBox) <> CustomControl (ItemsControl, ContentControl, Control) <> Subclass Visual.

Comment: Okay I think you gave me a bump in the right direction. Thank you very much for your time!